# Dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my Acer Aspire E E5-573G-52G3 and I was able to boot into Ubuntu one time.  After that one time I have no choice to boot into anything but windows.  I have run a boot-repair and still nothing.  I also have never seen the GRUB menu, when I booted into Ubuntu the first time it was in my F12 boot menu while booting up.

How do I fix this so I am able to boot up Ubuntu next to Windows?

Comment: You need to make sure Fast Startup is turned off in Windows and Secure Boot is turned off in the BIOS settings

Comment: Yes I have also done both of those things and still just starts up straight into windows!

Comment: Hmm. Well I'd start off with trying to reinstall with a supported version of Ubuntu. 14.10 reached its end-of-life in early 2015. Try 15.10, 14.04 or even 12.04.

Comment: ok ill try that

Answer (score 0):

Intsalling Ubuntu along side of Windows is really simple
I''m not really sure what happen with your installation but it seems to me that maybe yo did not properly install Ubuntu.

This post may Shed some like on what you need to do to get things up and running https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot?_ga=1.51001513.1619790069.1435447670

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have done everything but the last and most important step. To setup your UEFI/BIOS to boot to the boot loader.

The only thing you need to change is actually a small code in the MBR (Master Boot Record) inside the first hard disk (or the EFI partition). Change the boot code to point to your boot loader in Ubuntu.

Save your changes. Restart and enjoy your Utopic Unicorn, or your assembly line windows, whichever you boot to.

Comment: How do I change the code in the MBR inside the hard disk?

Comment: Here's a great page concerning the MBR:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Mbr   which is a great place to start; then after reading that article, at the bottom of that page there is another link concerning MultiOSBoot. Read that as well to get a full understanding.